# Searching for exact file extension using sh or bash on macOS (syntax issue)

Tags: macos, grep, find, sh

Looking for files with .pst or .pst extension. A few apps have files in their bundles that have either/both extensions, so excluding them.

After some testing, found this script works:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /Users -type f -not -path "*AnApplication.app*" | grep -i "*.pst$" > /path/to/search-result.txt

exit 0
```

However it is returning *.dpst" files. which I thought would not happen given the `grep -i "*.pst$"` part of the command.

We are using the `$` to ensure search returns extensions, and not files with ".pst" in the path or middle of name (Example: `myFile.pst.doc` or `/path/my.pst.files/`).

Our goal is to find *only* files ending in ".pst", what am I doing rong? :)

Comment: [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and regex are NOT same...  `grep -i '\.pst$'` might work... not sure how the regex `*.pst$` even matched anything

Comment: `grep` is not needed here I feel.. try `find /Users -type f -not -path "*AnApplication.app*" -iname '*.pst'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the huge help, my apologies for the belated response. Here is what we ended up going with:

`find /Users -type f -not -path '*AnApplication.app*' -iname '*.pst'`